# Сравнение символа строки с VbNewLine (VbCrLf) не срабатывает

Tags: строки, vb.net, visual-basic

Сравнение не срабатывает из-за чего цикл не останавливается, и в итоге программа аварийно завершается при выходе за границы строки.

```
Module Module1
    Function ReadUntilNewLIne(str As String)
        Dim currentIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim line As String = ""
        While str(currentIndex) <> vbCrLf
            line &= str(currentIndex)
            currentIndex += 1
        End While
        Return line
    End Function
    Sub Main()
        Dim arr(2) As String
        Dim line As String
        Dim str As String = "Hello" & vbNewLine
        str &= "How are you?" & vbNewLine
        str &= "Bye" & vbNewLine
        line = ReadUntilNewLIne(str)
        Console.WriteLine(str)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

**Как правильно сравнить символ с символом переноса строки?**

Comment: `str(currentIndex)` как бы возвращает 1 байт/символ. Тогда как `vbNewLine/vbCrLf`, внезапно, двухбайтовый...

Comment: @Akina, только двухсимвольный, а не двухбайтовый. А двухбайтовые и так все символы, т. к. у нас utf16.

Comment: @Qwertiy А, ну да... хотя это технический момент, не влияющий на суть источника проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Function ReadUntilNewLIne(str As String)
    Return Split(str, vbNewLine)(0)
End Function
```

---

> @JustLearn *я не понимаю, что значит (0) после split(str, vbnewline).*

Функция `Split` делит строку по заданному разделителю в массив строк с `Option Base 0`.

Т.е. `Split(str, vbNewLine)` делит значение из переменной `str` по разделителю `vbNewLine` (символы новой строки) - иными словами, по строке на элемент. В результат получается некий `array`. И теперь добавим эти самые скобки - получим `array(0)` - т.е. нулевой элемент массива, или самая первая строка из переменной.

А всё...

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает. Но я не понимаю, что значит (0) после split(str, vbnewline). Объясните, пожалуйста

Comment: @JustLearn Добавил пояснение.